# How to change a pointer inside a function without reference?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference

The following code does not compile because the casted pointer is an rvalue and can't be converted to a reference. Is that correct?

```
void func1(base*& ptr)
{
    func2((derived*)ptr);
}

template<typename T>
void func2(T*& ptr) { /* assign something to pointer */ }
```

The conversion would be possible if the parameter of the template function would be `const` but if that is the case, there is no assignment possible. What is a good way to solve this problem? Using a pointer to pointer as parameter type?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I have to downcast the `base`-pointer and assign a object to it using `func2`. The downcast is necessary because I need the sizeof information about the object in `func2`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I don't think you can do such a cast.

Comment: Aaaah I don't know why I haven't tried to cast to a reference directly. Thanks :)
@Barry The cast did work

Comment: @Barry Yup, that's right. cwde: Please don't use that cast.

Comment: @Barry Can you explain why not? As I said, it did work for this particular problem.

Comment: @cwde That's because you didn't use the `static`/`dynamic_cast` and went with the cast notation which resolved to a `reinterpret_cast` which is not the same as a downcast. If you used `static`/`dynamic_cast` you'd get an error like you should.